# Can I create a Snowflake ODBC DSN in Windows via the command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a 64-bit ODBC data source using the Snowflake ODBC driver in Windows 10 via the command line (for inclusion in a script). Is this possible using either a command-line tool such as **odbcconf.exe** or a PowerShell cmdlet such as **Add-OdbcDsn**, and if so, could anybody provide an example of valid syntax they have used to do so?

I have done this successfully in the past with other ODBC drivers, such as:

**Oracle Instant Client via odbcconf.exe:**

```
C:\Windows\System32\odbcconf.exe /A {CONFIGSYSDSN "Oracle in instantclient64" "DSN=Example_DSN|Server=Example_Server"}
```

**SQL Server via Add-OdbcDsn:**

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "Example_DSN" -DriverName "SQL Server" -DsnType "System" -Platform "32-bit" -SetPropertyValue @("Server=Example_Server","Trusted_Connection=Yes","Database=Example_Database")
```

However, I have been unsuccessful in using similar commands to create a DSN using the Snowflake ODBC driver.

I am using the following article for guidance: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-windows.html

For reference, I can create a DSN via the **"ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)"** GUI by selecting the **"SnowflakeDSIIDriver"** driver and filling in the data source, user, and server attributes in the **"Snowflake Configuration Dialog"** window, so I know it's possible create a DSN using this driver; I just can't figure out how to do it via the command line.

In the case of either of these **odbcconf.exe** commands:

```
C:\Windows\System32\odbcconf.exe /A {CONFIGSYSDSN "SnowflakeDSIIDriver" "DSN=Example_DSN"}

C:\Windows\System32\odbcconf.exe /A {CONFIGSYSDSN "SnowflakeDSIIDriver" "DSN=Example_DSN|Server=EXAMPLE.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com Database=Example_Database Schema=Example_Schema Warehouse=Example_WH Role=Example_Role Tracing=4 Authenticator=externalbrowser"}
```

Instead of creating the DSN, the **"Snowflake Configuration Dialog"** windows pops up as if I had attempted to create the DSN via the **"ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)"** GUI. Only the **"Data source"** field is populated with the value I placed after **"DSN="**. All other fields are blank, regardless of how many additional attributes I try to pass in the command:

[Snowflake Configuration Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCtKC.png)

If I add the user and server manually when the dialog window pops up and then click "OK," the DSN does get created; however, I do also receive an error message (I get this same error if I select "cancel" on the dialog window as well):

> "CONFIGSYSDSN: Unable to create a data source for the 'SnowflakeDSIIDriver' driver: Driver's ConfigDSN, ConfigDriver, or ConfigTranslator failed with error code -2147467259."

(Obviously, this doesn't solve the problem, as my intent would be for the command alone to create the DSN without user interaction.)

In the case of **Add-OdbcDsn** via PowerShell:

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "Example_DSN" -DriverName "SnowflakeDSIIDriver" -DsnType "System" -Platform "64-bit"
```

The command just seems to hang indefinitely until I cancel it. I never see any visible error messages, and I *don't* get the **"Snowflake Configuration Dialog"** window.

Does anybody have any suggestions I could try, and/or does anybody know for sure whether this is possible or if it's simply not supported by the Snowflake ODBC driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this but the Snowflake driver configurations must be defined using registry keys.

The answers above are correct but not very descriptive on the solution.  They led me to be able to script this in Powershell.

Issues:

1. When attempting to use Powershell command "Add-OdbcDsn" to configure the snowflake DSN the command hangs and will never complete (my guess is that the configuration windows opens silently and is waiting for information to be input).
2. ODBCCONF.EXE (ODBCCONF [switches] action) fails stating invalid actions.

Solution:
Here is a full solution that worked for me (specifically tested on Windows 10 with driver snowflake64_odbc-3.2.0). It uses the registry to configure the ODBC User DSN but could be modified for a System DSN.

Description: Programmatically configure Snowflake ODCB DNS for Windows instance

Prerequisite: Install Snowflake Driver (SnowflakeDSIIDriver).  This can be downloaded from Snowflake

HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake is the registry path where the User DSN is configured
HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake is the registry path where the System DSN is configured

## This path needs to be created if it doesn't exist

- New-Item -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake' | out-null

## These are the responses to the Snowflake DSN configuration

- new-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake' -name "UID" -value %user_name% | out-null
- new-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake' -name "SERVER" -value "%server_name.snowflakecomputing.com%" | out-null
- new-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake' -name "DATABASE" -value "%data_base%" | out-null
- new-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake' -name "SCHEMA" -value "%schema%" | out-null
- new-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake' -name "WAREHOUSE" -value "%warehouse%" | out-null
- new-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake' -name "TRACING" -value "%number%" | out-null
- new-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\Snowflake' -name "AUTHENTICATOR" -value "%authenticator%"

## This is the mapping for the configuration to the DSN

- new-itemproperty -path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources' -name "Snowflake" -value "SnowflakeDSIIDriver" | out-null

Note: Substitute %value% for your values.  The registry keys are REG_SZ (String Values) and the -names are case sensitive.  If you delete the ODBC DSN then the registry entries will be removed.

Once executed you can verify configuration by launching ODBC and checking/testing the configuration.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for providing this alternative solution. I haven't tested it, but I have no doubt it'll work. The key takeaway for me is odbcconf.exe and Add-OdbcDsn simply will not work up through the current version of the Snowflake ODBC driver (3.2.0). The only way to create a data source via a script is by creating the necessary registry keys/values directly. Your approach would work well for anybody who wants to keep things in PowerShell and keep it all in one script (no references to external .reg files).

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but the [Doc's](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-parameters.html#setting-parameters-in-windows) mention the registry settings location. So you could manually complete, and then "read" the registry settings set, and then inject those in your scripts.

Comment: I think this is the best approach I have currently, and it did work once I nailed down a couple details. Specifically, for a 64-bit ODBC connection, there are two subkeys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI that need to be considered: one subkey will be created with the DSN name, but a value will also be added in the "ODBC Data Sources" subkey, where the value name matches the DSN, and the data is a string containing the ODBC driver name. I believe I missed the second part when testing this previously and concluded this method wouldn't work. Thank you!